# Change Chrome Extension User Agent for URL

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently building a Chrome extension and I would like to change the user agent of the Chrome extension when requesting a file from the server but it keeps requesting it with the default Chrome user agent. I've used Chrome extension plugins source code to change on request and it still will not happen. I've inserted a .htaccess only allowing one specific user agent and I would like to see if I can even do it with Chrome extensions.

This is the `JS` code I'm using to get the file from the server.

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'FILE BEING IMPORTED/REQUESTED';
document.head.appendChild(imported);
```

I've also tried this and set the permissions correctly in `manifest.json`

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    for(var i=0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i){
        if(details.requestHeaders[i].name === "User-Agent"){
            details.requestHeaders[i].value = "Desired User Agent Here";

            break;
        }
    }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
}, {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works. Are you sure you have both the "webRequest" and "webRequestBlocking" permissions plus the correct host permissions in your manifest file?
It should not make a difference but are you including the imported script in an extension page?

Comment: I've went on a different approach on this but yeah I had both permissions on my manifest but thank you.

Comment: @varProjectsWhat was the different approach? I'm getting this working intermittently using the above. Strange